# java query to update the table in the database by retrieving values from the text box

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

hi i have a table in database with 3 columns say numb(int) its primary key, itemname(string), cost(int);  [database look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c7lgd.png)
Now i have an front end where user wants to update this table,he provides the the data in the respective fields, retrieving this data i have to update my table.  [front end](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WR4cS.png)
  but this query is not working i tried many ways

```
   Statement st=con.createStatement();
   sql="UPDATE table item SET itemname='newitm' WHERE numb='no'";
   st.executeUpdate(sql);
```

newitm is a variable retrieving itemname, and no will store primary key value.

Comment: sql query to update is `update item set itemname='value' where numb='no'` and not `update table item ...`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suggest you to use PreparedStatement instead of Statement.

```
PreparedStatement stmt=con.prepareStatement("UPDATE item SET itemname=? WHERE numb=?");  
stmt.setString(1, newitm);  
stmt.setInt(2, no);

int i = stmt.executeUpdate();  
System.out.println(i + " records updated");
```

Comment: Parameter index out of range (2 > number of parameters, which is 1). what is the problem here

Comment: Sorry, my mistake. Try fixed code (remove quotes around first `?`)

Answer (score 0):

Change sql query to following

```
sql="UPDATE item SET itemname='newitm' WHERE numb='no'";
```

It'll definitely work..

Comment: sql="UPDATE item SET cost ='newcst' WHERE numb ='no'";  this query is having no error but its not affecting my table.

Comment: `numb(int) its primary key`, but you try to run query `WHERE numb ='no'`?